# Get input fields on one line while staying responsive

Tags: css, forms, input, responsive-design, contact-form-7

I am trying to make a simple form with website, email and "submit". I want it to look like this:
[image]

I've been searching similar questions on here and found a couple solutions using table or flex to make all the fields on one line, but then there's some formatting (not centered) and responsive issues :/

Here is the HTML for my form:

```html
<div class="seoaudit">
<div class="seoinput"><label style="color: #24535d; font-family: 'Muli'; font-style: italic; font-size: 18px;"> Your Website URL
    [url* url-613]</label></div>
<div class="seoinput"><label style="color: #24535d; font-family: 'Muli'; font-style: italic; font-size: 18px;"> Your Email
    [email* your-email] </label></div>


<div class="seoinput">
<br/>
[submit "Send Request!"]</div>
</div>
```

This is the current CSS I have:

```css
<div class="seoaudit">
<div class="seoinput"><label style="color: #24535d; font-family: 'Muli'; font-style: italic; font-size: 18px;"> Your Website URL
    [url* url-613]</label></div>
<div class="seoinput"><label style="color: #24535d; font-family: 'Muli'; font-style: italic; font-size: 18px;"> Your Email
    [email* your-email] </label></div>


<div class="seoinput">
<br/>
[submit "Send Request!"]</div>
</div>
```

I also have this in the CSS for my contact form 7 forms (which is what this is built on) but I'm not sure it affects it:

```css
.wpcf7-form-style {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
}

.wpcf7-form input[type="text"], .wpcf7-form input[type="email"], .wpcf7-form input[type="url"] {
margin: 9px auto 0 !important;
    }
```

So it looks just how I want it on desktop :D  But when you get to tablet or mobile it just cuts of the form fields and all you can see on mobile is part of the URL input! Ahhh. I'm wondering if media queries is the move? Or if there's something I can apply to the entire form div that makes this go to another row(s) for tablet and mobile? I tried playing around with this too: http://jsfiddle.net/XAkXg/

But no luck. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Show the code you used when trying to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries to attain the layout you wanted in small screens.
Example:

```
@media (min-width:480px){
    your input styles here...
}
```